# How do I convert PCL into .netstandard based library

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm-light, portable-class-library, .net-standard

Basically I have xamarin project which uses MVVMlight inside PCL and the PCL has all the viewmodels with the help of MVVMlight.

I would like to turn the PCL into .Netstandard library so I can have access to more .net based APIs but I am confused whether MVVMlight will be supported over there ?

I couldn't find any easy way to convert so far as well

Can anybody shed some light on this

Comment: MvvmLight does not support `.NET Standard` quite yet. Thus you will have to use `.NET Standard's` portability shim. https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-does-net-standard-work-with-portable-class-libraries-pcls There's also a `PCL Compatibility` section on the main docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library

Comment: @JonDouglas - Thanks for bringing this to attention :)

Comment: @Sharath, what was your final solution? I don't see a selected post.

Answer (score 2):

As of today, none of the MVVM Light packages is compatible with .NET Standard 1.4

Answer (score 1):

The process is described in the link below:
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/dotnet/1317/dotnet-standard-cross-platform-development

Have a look at the middle of the page (above Image 4)
You basically start with a PCL and the retarget it to .net Standard in the `Project Properties` page on the `Libraries` tab. Click on the link saying `.net Platform Standard`. You are also able to convert back to PCL if needed.

Comment: Oh Thanks But How about its impact on MVVMlight ?

Comment: There is an API implemented 'inside' the Standard assemblies to ensure portability. As long as your MVVM assemblies make use of standard .net I have not come across any compatibility problems. It's purpose is to allow usage across different frameworks. Also note, that the smallest common denominator still applies in terms of available and compatible features. You do not make certain framework features available - you ensure compatibility across frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

PCL is not a out of box project, it is also a .Net project that targeted to many different platforms as above @Snympi mentioned in his answer. Apart from that I mentioned 2 important link here, that will help you.

[Xamarin Help Blog](https://xamarinhelp.com/dot-net-standard-pcl-xamarin-forms/) and one is from [Xamarin Forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/86139/targeting-net-standard)

Take a look on above links..!!

Comment: Thanks for the links